# Use internal network for the Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

All nodes have two network interfaces for internal and external networks. I need to set up a self-managed Kubernetes cluster that is using only the internal network except NodePorts must be open also on the external network.

This config is used with the `kubeadm init`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
bootstrapTokens:
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: "10.x.x.x"
```

Starting kubelet:

```
/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --address=10.x.x.y --node-ip=10.x.x.y
```

1. What is the difference between `--address` and `--node-ip` I am unable to understand from the documentation.
2. Is it enough to do what I want from the Kubernetes perspective? I am unable to run Istio, so trying to narrow down the issue.

Self managed Kubernetes 1.23.4

Comment: First thing is using flags to start `kubelet` is deprecated, it should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information. Answer to question: 1 - `address` is on which node will listed to (it's about interfaces from my understanding). `node-ip` is used for advertising IP to control-plane. I'm not sure how `nodeports` should be exposed separately to another interface. Based on config it's either everything or nothing.